# How to save breakpoints in selenium ide chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, save, breakpoints, selenium-ide

Is there a way to save breakpoints in Selenium IDE (Chrome)? I have a test which fills up one form, submits it and fills another form on another page etc. I want to pause this flow with breakpoints, maybe change some fields etc. If I save the project (.side), it won't save the breakpoints. It's very tedious to add them every time I start the tests.

How to solve this?

SIDE version 3.17.0
Chrome Mac version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use command to save it ( `"command": "debugger"`).
The issue is that you don't have a command that can enable / disable those debugger commands like the (`Ctrl` + `y`). :(

But once your debugger commands are saved then any text editor can switch them on/off by replacing `["command": "debugger"]` , with `["command": "//debugger"]`